# Change in proof environment

Tags: symbols

Could anybody tell me how to put a box at the end of proof, when the last line is a centered math formula? Thanks. The example is as follows.

```
\begin{proposition} 
 blah blah
\end{proposition}
\begin{proof} Since something is true, we have 
\begin{center}
$A = B$.
\end{center}
\end{proof}
```

I have found the answer in the above case. But there is still another question when I want to use it in the array case. In this case the qedsymbol doesn't flushright.

```
\begin{proposition} 
 blah blah
\end{proposition}
\begin{proof} Since something is true, we have 
\[\begin{array}{cc}
 a&b\\c&d\qedhere
\end{array}\]
\end{proof}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing which proof environment you are using.

Comment: Look for `\qedhere` on the site.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  However, you have only posted a code snippet - it doesn't tell us which package/documentclass defines your proof environment.  Also a centered equation is usually produced with `displaymath` or `equation*` (the latter from `amsmath` or `mathtools`).  Using a `center` environment will defeat several of the automatic tests.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much. I have found the answer.

Comment: @Andrew Swann:This is what I need. Thanks. \makeatletter \renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname] {\par\pushQED{\qed}\normalfont\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax\trivlist\item[\hskip\labelsep\bfseries#1\@addpunct{:}]\ignorespaces}{\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse} \makeatother

Comment: Which package, or packages, do you load that provide definitions of environments called `proposition` and `proof`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you're loading the `amsthm` package since you make use of an environment called `proof`. With this package loaded, the following code will give you the QED symbol (say, a hollow square) at the end of the display-math environment; note that the macro `\qedhere` has to be the last item of the display-math environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof} Since something is true, we have 
\[
\begin{array}{cc}
  a&b\\
  c&d
\end{array} \qedhere
\] 
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you notice that the square box is not on the last line?

Comment: @ksj03 - Actually, this very much depends on what you mean by "on the last line". In the example I've given (which is the example you gave...), the box is aligned on the *baseline of the equation* which, in the case of a 2x2 `array`, runs smack through the middle of the array. The box thus *is* placed on the equation's baseline. If for some reason you want the box aligned on the second line of the `array`, all you need to do is provide a `[b]` alignment specification to the array, i.e., write `\begin{array}[b]{cc}`. Does this make sense?

Comment: By the way, where did you learn these stuffs from?

Comment: @ksj03 - Mostly writing my own working papers in LaTeX, as well as time and again consulting the books *The LaTeX Companion* and *The TeXbook* to figure how to solve various issues...

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for the `automatic` placement of end marks in theorems is the `ntheorem` package, in my opinion. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}

 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
 \makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{proof}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep\theorem@headerfont\MakeUppercase ##1\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip \labelsep\theorem@headerfont\MakeUppercase ##1\ ##3\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{proof}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{:}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\begin{theorem}[Some theorem]\label{thm:some-theorem}
This is an important theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
This is a very important proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[of theorem Some theorem]
This is a very important proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[of \Cref{thm:some-theorem}]
This is a very important proof.
\begin{align*}
    a & = b\\ c & = d.
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can't use your package, since I have to use something else.

Comment: @ksj03 - What would that "something else" be?

Comment: Because I customized my theorem environment, which is not compatiable with the package{ntheorem}.

Comment: @ksj03: Are you sure? I hardly can imagine any customisation that couldn't be done with `ntheorem`.

Comment: My setting:\newtheoremstyle{plain}
  {\topsep}  
  {\topsep}   
  {\itshape}  
  {0pt}      
  {\bfseries} 
  { }         
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} 
  {\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{(#3)}}       
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\makeatletter \renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname] {\par\pushQED{\qed}\normalfont\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax\trivlist\item[\hskip\labelsep\bfseries#1\@addpunct{:}]\ignorespaces}
{\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse} \makeatother

Comment: @ksj03: I modified the code to (hopefully) satisfy the same settings as yours. As far as I understand your  code, your `plain` style is more or less the default with `ntheorem`. Not sure whether you want to incorporate the section number in theorem number, but that is easy to change.